# Can I download files by ftp simultaneously?

Tags: objective-c, download, ftp

I need to download by ftp many files. 
How can I download them simultaneously? 
I tried:

1. from [SimpleFTPSample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html) with NSInputStream,
2. with NSURLConnection and
3. with NSURLSession 
   and always receive the same speed (files are downloaded one by one).
   I tried to create class instance that perform all job in another thread with dispatch_async, but thenI have to schedule inputstream or url connection in main run loop (to get notified about downloaded status) and get even worse result.

Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: Think about your problem. You are ultimately limited by the internet connection to the device. Assuming your remote FTP server has ample bandwidth, does it make sense to try and cram two large files through your skinky pipe?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thanks for reply. I just don't know how to figure out why downloading is slow. Is it OK, that when many NSInputStreams has received 'open' action, but  next stream handle event NSStreamEventOpenCompleted only when the previous one becomes closed? I expected that they would work independently. Maybe I can create another port? Sorry, if this question is so stupid, as I know about this nothing.